# JQuery toggle text and class on click without writing redundant code

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Code is working as expected, but it is redundant and would get old if we have more than a few items. **How can we shorten it?**

**[Codepen Demo](https://codepen.io/fraktar/pen/ybxOpB)**

```
$(".i1").click(function () {
    $(".i1 .added").fadeOut(function () {
    $(".i1 .added").text(($(".i1 .added").text() == 'Deposit') ? 'Added' : 
        'Deposit').fadeIn();
        $(this).toggleClass("highlight");
    })
})
    $(".i2").click(function () {
    $(".i2 .added").fadeOut(function () {
    $(".i2 .added").text(($(".i2 .added").text() == 'Deposit') ? 'Added' : 
        'Deposit').fadeIn();
        $(this).toggleClass("highlight");
    })
})
$(".i3").click(function () {
    $(".i3 .added").fadeOut(function () {
    $(".i3 .added").text(($(".i3 .added").text() == 'Deposit') ? 'Added' : 
        'Deposit').fadeIn();
        $(this).toggleClass("highlight");
    })
})
```

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: can we indent please? so hard to read :'(

Comment: Given that you like hard to read to code: `$(".i1,.i2,.i3").click(function() { $(".added", this).fadeOut(function() { $(this).text(($(this).text() == 'Deposit') ? 'Added' : 'Deposit').fadeIn();$(this).toggleClass("highlight"); }) });` would be easier if you could give them all the same class instead of `i1` `i2` etc.

Comment: Belongs on codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change your js code to [**this**](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ybxJVV)

```
$(".item-btn").click(function () {
  $(this).find('.added').fadeOut(function () {
    var text = $(this).text();

    $(this).text((text == 'Deposit') ? 'Added' : 'Deposit').fadeIn();
    $(this).toggleClass("highlight");
  })
})
```

Comment: Perfect. This means I can also remove the redundant classes (i1, i2...) from my code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add a common class for each element you want to trigger this events, then call it only once.

Like this:

```
$('.common-class').on('click', function() {
   var added = $(this).find('.added');

   added.fadeout(function() {
      $(this).text((added.text() == 'Deposit') ? 'Added' : 'Deposit').fadeIn();
      $(this).toggleClass("highlight");
   });
});
```